# How do you reduce latency for calls fowarded from an Australian twilio number?

Tags: twilio

We're experiencing 1 second call latencies to calls forwarded from an Australian twilio number which makes Twilio call forwarding unusable.

Is there any way to reduce this?

Is there a better alternative to Twilio for this solution in Australia?

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is for /programming/ questions. Please try superuser for general software questions.

Answer (score 2):

Restomm is an open source based alternative to look at. Restcomm is compatible with the [Twilio APIs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest). You can setup connectivity via local ITSPs in Australia for best latency.

http://www.telestax.com/restcomm/

Also available on AWS Marketplace: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00FFHJ6SU